# C# - From NetworkStream to XElement managing different encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, xelement

I've an application that search XML over the network (using TcpClient), these XML have various encoding (one site in UTF8, other in Windows-1252). I would like encode all of these XML in UTF-8 (always) to be sure I'm clean.

How can I do the conversion from the NetworkStream to an XElement encoding correctly all data?

I've this :

```
NetworkStream _clientStream = /* ... */;
MemoryStream _responseBytes = new MemoryStream();

// serverEncoding -> Xml Encoding I get from server
// _UTF8Encoder -> Local encoder (always UTF8)

try
{
    _clientStream.CopyTo(_responseBytes);

    if (serverEncoding != _UTF8Encoder)
    {
        MemoryStream encodedStream = new MemoryStream();
        string line = null;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_responseBytes))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(encodedStream))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(
                        Encoding.Convert(serverEncoding, _UTF8Encoder, serverEncoding.GetBytes(line))
                        );
                }
            }
        }
        _responseBytes = encodedStream;
    }

    _responseBytes.Position = 0;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(_responseBytes))
    {
        xmlResult = XElement.Load(reader, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

Have you a better solution (and by ignoring all '\0' ?).

---

### Edit

This works :

```
byte[] b = _clientStream.ReadToEnd();
var text = _UTF8Encoder.GetString(b, 0, b.Length);
xmlResult = XElement.Parse(text, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

But this not :

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(_clientStream, false))
    xmlResult = XElement.Load(reader, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

I don't understand why ...

Comment: For starters, don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: I removed code from catch clause, not interesting here, it's ok ;)

Comment: What happens if you create a `StreamReader` and call `ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: It waits (as a note : I'm using the Compact Framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a `StreamReader` around the `NetworkStream`, passing the encoding of the stream, then pass it to `XElement.Load`:

```
XElement elem
using(var reader = new StreamReader = new StreamReader(_clientStream, serverEncoding))
    elem = XElement.Load(reader);
```

There is no point in manually transcoding it to a different encoding.

Comment: It doesn't work. Program block on "Load" because it doesn't perform a Read operation ... But when I do : reader.BaseStream.Read() ... I got a result back...

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  Are you sure you have the correct encoding?

Comment: Yes, sure... Is the encoding blocking when not correct !? If yes, why not just throw an exception? ...

Comment: If you pass an encoding with multi-byte chars, it can block forever while waiting for the next byte in a multi-byte char if it's at the end of the stream.

Comment: I removed encoding from StreamReader, same problem ...                     `using(var reader = new StreamReader(_clientStream, false))
                        elem = XElement.Load(reader, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);`